# Downloading uploaded files using Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to download uploaded files in Code igniter, but it doesn't work. 
Here is my controller(download.php). If someone can post an example highly appreciate.

```
<?php  
   class Download extends CI_Controller {   
      public function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
      }     
      public function index() { 
            $this->load->view('vwHomeHeader', $data);
            $this->load->view('vwHomeMenu', $data);
            $this->load->view('download', $data);
            $this->load->view('vwHomeFooter', $data); 
      }     
public function download ($file_path = "") {         
            $this->load->helper('download');            
            $data['download_file'] = $file_path;      
            $this->load->view("download",$data);
            redirect(current_url(), "refresh");                      
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is the view file(download.php)

```
<?php
if( ! empty($download_file))
    {
        $data = file_get_contents(base_url("/upload/".$download_file)); 
        $name = $download_file;
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe the expected behaviour and the actual one

Answer (score 0):

modify as you see fit (controller, no need for a view unless you want to use an anchor tag to the download controller url)

```
    if($file) {
        $filepath = FCPATH . 'uploads/projects/'.$ProjID.'/'.$file['file_name'];

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($filepath);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply... but what I really need is to display existing files in the 'upload' folder and when user select the file then download

Comment: Then use PHP to read the files in the location and list them, and then redirect to another controller and use this script.